# Need to create the empty entry depends on the column

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I'm having the three columns of table input xml, So the tgroup would be `<tgroup cols="3" colsep="0" rowsep="0">`

```
<row>
   <entry colname="col1" colsep="0" rowsep="0">Duty</entry>
   <entry colname="col2" colsep="0" rowsep="0"></entry>
   <entry colname="col3" colsep="0" rowsep="0">Correct</entry>
</row>
<row>
   <entry colname="col1" colsep="0" rowsep="0">Dollar</entry>
</row>
```

XSL I have tried is:

```
<xsl:template match="row">
    <row>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </row>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="entry">
    <entry>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </entry>
</xsl:template>
```

Output I got is:

```
<row>
   <entry>Duty</entry>
   <entry></entry>
   <entry>Correct</entry>
</row>
<row>
   <entry>Dollar</entry>
</row>
```

Excepted Output:

```
<row>
   <entry>Duty</entry>
   <entry></entry>
   <entry>Correct</entry>
</row>
<row>
   <entry>Dollar</entry>
   <entry></entry>
   <entry></entry>
</row>
```

Because of that I'm getting validation error and it's depending the tgroup column number. So I want to create the empty entry in the output depend on tgroup column number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even you can use the tgroup/@cols value in variable and try to use for generaring the entries like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" exclude-result-prefixes="xs" version="2.0">

    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="row">
        <row>
            <xsl:variable name="colno" select="../tgroup/@cols"/>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="count(entry) = $colno">
                    <xsl:apply-templates/>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:apply-templates/>
                    <xsl:for-each select="count(entry) + 1 to $colno">
                        <entry colname="{concat('col',.)}" colsep="0" rowsep="0"/>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </row>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Follow this link: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/6rewNxG

**OR**

If you want namest and nameend like spaning then you go with:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" exclude-result-prefixes="xs" version="2.0">

    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

        <xsl:template match="row">
        <row>
            <xsl:variable name="colno" select="../tgroup/@cols"/>
            <xsl:variable name="entrycount" select="count(entry)"/>
            <xsl:for-each select="entry">
                <entry>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
                    <xsl:if test="position() = last() and $colno != $entrycount">
                        <xsl:attribute name="namest" select="concat('col',position())"/>
                        <xsl:attribute name="nameend" select="concat('col',$colno)"/>
                    </xsl:if>
                    <xsl:apply-templates/>
                </entry>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </row>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Follow Link: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/6rewNxG/1

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
<xsl:template match="row">
    <row>
        <entry>
            <xsl:value-of select="entry[@colname='col1']"/>
        </entry>
        <entry>
            <xsl:value-of select="entry[@colname='col2']"/>
        </entry>
        <entry>
            <xsl:value-of select="entry[@colname='col3']"/>
        </entry>
    </row>
</xsl:template>
```

or perhaps just simply:

```
<xsl:template match="row">
    <row>
        <entry>
            <xsl:value-of select="entry[1]"/>
        </entry>
        <entry>
            <xsl:value-of select="entry[2]"/>
        </entry>
        <entry>
            <xsl:value-of select="entry[3]"/>
        </entry>
    </row>
</xsl:template>
```

or even:

```
<xsl:template match="row">
    <row>
        <xsl:variable name="entries" select="entry" />
        <xsl:for-each select="1 to 3">
            <entry>
                <xsl:value-of select="$entries[current()]"/>
            </entry>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </row>
</xsl:template>
```